How to regrid big matrix in Python without interpolation?
I need to re-grid fine matrix variable, called "fine_var" with dimensions of (12,1800,3600) (time lat lon) to coarse matrix variable, called "coarse_var" with dimension (12,180,360) (time, lat, lon), without interpolate the variable, but summing the contribution to each cell of fine matrix to the cell of coarse matrix.
To do this I created a loop below with python:
for ii  in range(len(ds.fine_var[0,:,0])-1):
for jj  in range(len(ds.fine_var[0,0,:])-1): 
    coarse_var[:,int(ii/10),int(jj/10)]+=ds.fine_var[:,ii,jj]

However, this loop is too heavy to compute and I was wondering if there is a light method in Python to create a coarse grid without interpolating the variable.
Can anyone please offer any assistance?
Any help is much appreciated!

You are not interpolating here you are averaging over the finely sampled data to produce a lower resolution coarse version. Interpolating means using the existing dataset to make estimates of the values on a finer grid.
I don't actually know the exact layout of arrays in your choice of language but I suspect that the order you are summing the arrays in may be the worst possible case for page faults and cache misses. IOW
for ii  in range(len(ds.fine_var[0,:,0])-1):
for jj  in range(len(ds_disk.fine_var[0,0,:])-1): 

Should be swapped for
for jj  in range(len(ds_disk.fine_var[0,0,:])-1): 
for ii  in range(len(ds.fine_var[0,:,0])-1):

And then it may well run fast enough for your purposes. Try this first!
You should also be aware that divides (apart from by 2^n) and a handful of special cases are expensive slow operations with high latency. Best avoided in fast code. Likewise for array write accesses and your simple loop code does 100 of them when only one is actually needed.
I can't write it in Python but I can suggest pseudocode that will make this code to average a fine dataset to a coarser grid much faster and cache local.
I'm assuming here that the array layout is something in memory that looks like:
 x[0,0] x[0,1] x[0,2] ...x[0,NX-1] x[1,0] x[1,1] ... x[1,NX-1] x[2,0]... ...x[NY-1,NX-1]

Following your index naming convention :
for jj = 0 to (NY-1)/10 
   jj10 = 10*jj
   for  ii = 0 to (NX-1)/10
      ii10 = 10*ii
      sum = 0;
      for  j = jj10 to jj10+9
         for i = ii10 to ii10+9
            sum += fine_var[i,jj10];
         next i
      next j
      coarse_var[ii,jj] = sum
   next ii
next jj

Just flipping the order of the ii,jj loops around in your original code might well be good enough if you only ever want to do this once! The object of the exercise is to make everything fit into the cache whilst it is work in progress. There may be further possible optimisations but I hope this will be fast enough. It avoids a lot of unnecessary array accesses and stores the final sum into the destination array once at the right position moving through the original array in steps of 10 rows at a time.
If you run through a large array with indexing in the wrong order then everything is a cache miss and glacially s-l--o---w. PS you might also want to normalise it by dividing by 100 (or not if it is per unit area).
